# Simplify a MySQL query that can have multiple input options using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that will query my database and needs to be able to query using one or all of four options.  The options are start sku, end sku (this is one option as there has to be a range to search), created by and date created.  I know I can do this using MANY if..elseif statements, but I have to think there is a better and easier way.  Here is what I have for code so far:

```
$start =mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['skuStart']);
$end = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skuEnd']);
$source = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['source']);
$processDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['processDate']);

if(!empty($start) && !empty($end) && empty($source) && empty($processDate)){
$result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where sku >= $start and sku <= $end");

 } elseif (empty($start) && empty($end) && !empty($source) && empty($processDate)){
$result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where created_by = '$source'");

 } elseif (empty($start) && empty($end) && empty($source) && !empty($processDate)) {
$result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where date_process = '$processDate'");

} elseif(!empty($start) && !empty($end) && !empty($source) && empty($processDate)){
$result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where sku >= $start and sku <= $end and created_by = '$source'");

} else {
$result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where sku >= '$start' and sku <= '$end' and created_by = '$source' and date_process = '$processDate'");
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $skuArray[$x] = $row['sku'];
        $isbnArray[$x] = $row['isbn13'];
        $qtyArray[$x] = $row['quantity'];
        $defectArray[$x] = $row['defect_id'];
        $sourceArray[$x] = $row['source_id'];
        $featureArray[$x] = $row['feature_id'];
        $locationArray[$x] = $row['location_id'];
        $processDateArray[$x] = $row['date_process'];
        $bookTypeArray[$x] = $row['book_type_id'];
        $createdByArray[$x] = $row['created_by'];
        $modifiedByArray[$x] = $row['modified_by'];

        $x++;
```

This very crude form is working, but is there a way to get the if elseif simplified?

NOTE: I know that I should be using PDO to prevent sql injection, but I have not fully learned that yet, so I am using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the issues you're already aware of - switching to PDO and using bound parameters - You could make your code a little clearer with the following:

```
<?php

$start          = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['skuStart']);
$end            = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skuEnd']);
$source         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['source']);
$processDate    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['processDate']);
$where          = array();

if(!empty($start))
{
    $where[] = 'sku >= ' . $start;
}

if(!empty($end))
{
    $where[] = 'sku <= ' . $end;
}

if(!empty($source))
{
    $where[] = 'created_by = \''.$source .'\'';
}

if(!empty($processDate))
{
    $where[] = 'date_process = \''.$processDate .'\'';
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM inventory';

if(count($where))
{
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
}

$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $skuArray[$x] = $row['sku'];
        $isbnArray[$x] = $row['isbn13'];
        $qtyArray[$x] = $row['quantity'];
        $defectArray[$x] = $row['defect_id'];
        $sourceArray[$x] = $row['source_id'];
        $featureArray[$x] = $row['feature_id'];
        $locationArray[$x] = $row['location_id'];
        $processDateArray[$x] = $row['date_process'];
        $bookTypeArray[$x] = $row['book_type_id'];
        $createdByArray[$x] = $row['created_by'];
        $modifiedByArray[$x] = $row['modified_by'];

        $x++;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', 'user', 'passwd');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY ";

$where  = array ();
$params = array ();
if (! empty($start) && ! empty($end) {
    $where[] = " sku >= :start AND sku <= :end ";
    $params['start'] = $start;
    $params['end']   = $end;
}
if (! empty($source)) {
    $where[] = " created_by = :source ";
    $params['source'] = $source;
}
if (! empty($processDate)) {
    $where[] = " date_process = :date_process ";
    $params['date_process'] = $processDate;
}

if (! empty($where)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . join (' AND ', $where);
}

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($params);

while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I am interested in your answer since you are using PDO, my question is then, do I need the $db = new PDO ... if I am using another file to hold my db info?

Comment: @Jim To use PDO you'll always have to instantiate a PDO object somewhere, either in this file or another one. This object wraps a connection to the database. You could instantiate it once in a bootstrap file and pass it around or put it in a registry to reuse everywhere you need a connection to the DB.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am going to start trying this with the updates I will be doing in the next few days.

Comment: @Jim Good stuff! I think PDO's API makes it nicer to use than the bare mysql_* functions. You'll probably want to enable reporting errors as exceptions though, which makes it easier to debug when things go wrong. Just do this after you've instantiated `$db` as your PDO object: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will add that to my code.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = array();
if (!empty($start))
  $q[] = "sku >= '$start'";
if (!empty($end))
  $q[] = "sku <= '$end'";
#...
$q = join(') AND (', $q);
$q = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE ($q)";
```

or you could take this one step further:

```
$params = array(
   'skuStart' => "sku >= '##'",
   'skuEnd' => "'sku <= '##'",
   #...
);

$q = array();
foreach($params as $k=>$sql) {
   $v = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$k]);
   if (!empty($v)) {
     $sql = tr_replace('##', $v, $sql);
     $q[] = $sql;
   }
}
$q = join(') AND (', $q);
```

And then you could add types for verification, and other stuff the enhance your metadata and build your small framework...

Whenever you feel that you're repeating yourself you should check for an existing solution (library/framework) or build your one... [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder. For example https://github.com/jstayton/QueryBuilder (first founded in google) if you don't use any framework.