# PDO multi-Filter sql query

Tags: php

Is there a simpler way for me to code this and perform the same thing without having to have so many queries? Im trying to add pagination (not included in code here) and it works on my ALL query, but the AND / OR queries give funny results and is becoming a headache. Other than that the filtering of results works perfect just need pagination.

```
$filter = isset($_POST['filter']) ? $_POST['filter'] : null;
$status = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : null;

if(empty($filter) && empty($status)) {

    //echo 'ALL query';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM _product JOIN _module_type ON module_type = module_id';
    $sth = $link->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array());
    $result = $sth->fetchall();

} else {
    // display result if filter AND status are selected
    if(!empty($filter) && !empty($status)) {

        //echo 'AND query';
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM _product JOIN _module_type ON module_type = module_id WHERE module_type = :filter AND product_status = :status';
        $sth = $link->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':filter' => $filter, ':status' => $status));
        $result = $sth->fetchall();

    } else {
        // display result if filter OR status are selected
        if(!empty($filter) || !empty($status)) {

            //echo 'OR query';
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM _product JOIN _module_type ON module_type = module_id WHERE module_type = :filter OR product_status = :status';
            $sth = $link->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute(array(':filter' => $filter, ':status' => $status));
            $result = $sth->fetchall();

        }
    }
}

//test sql
echo $sql.'<br />';

$bgcolor = '';
foreach($result as $key => $value) {

    if(($bgcolor=='#ffffff') ? $bgcolor='#f1f1f1' : $bgcolor='#ffffff') {

    echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">';
    echo '<td>'.$value['product_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['product_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['product_type'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['module_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['product_price'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['product_status'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
}
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I had a similar question this morning.  See the answers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740066/simplify-a-mysql-query-that-can-have-multiple-input-options-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And My Second thought:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM _product JOIN _module_type ON module_type = module_id WHERE';
if(!empty($filter) || !empty($status)){
    $sql .= ' module_type = :filter '.(!empty($filter) && !empty($status) ? 'AND' : 'OR').' product_status = :status';
    $sth = $link->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(':filter', $filter);
    $sth->bindValue(':status', $status);
}else{ $sth = $link->prepare($sql); }
$result = $sth->execute();
```

It needs testing and as truth said you might not need the OR but that is upto exactly how your form and filtering works tbh, but I am gonna leave it at that it should give you pointers to move to the next stage.

Edit again:

Couldn't help myself, here is a third possibility:

```
$params = array();
$where = array();

if(!empty($filter)){
    $params[':filter'] = $filter;
    $where[] = 'module_type = :filter';
}
if(!empty($status)){
    $params[':status'] = $status;
    $where[] = 'product_status = :status';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM _product JOIN _module_type ON module_type = module_id'.(sizeof($where) > 0 ? ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where) : '');

$sth = $link->prepare($sql);
foreach($params as $k=>$v) $sth->bindValue($k, $v);
$result = $sth->execute();
```

Comment: I tried your second example, I moved the "WHERE" to sql concatenate string before module_type, to make sure it shows all results on page load. I also tweaked the else sth. That works good now, Im going to test your 3rd example now.

Comment: @dynamo Make sure to take my latest edit, there was a problem with the original post

Answer (score 1):

My thought is to iterate the `$_POST` array and bind only the variables you need.

You are misunderstanding the use of AND and OR. If only one of the two is selected, you don't need to OR on the second one!

```
<?php

    /**
     * @param PDO   $pdo        Database connection
     * @param array $parameters Parameters (status, filter)
     *
     * @return array            The resultset returned from the query
     */
    function select_product(\PDO $pdo, array $parameters = array()) {
        $query = <<<MySQL
SELECT *
  FROM _product
  JOIN _module_type
    ON module_type = module_id

MySQL;
        if (!empty($parameters)) {
            $query .= "WHERE ";
            $where_clauses = array();
            foreach ($parameters as $param => $value) {
                $where_clauses[] = "$param = :$param";
            }
            $where_clauses = implode(" AND ", $where_clauses);
            $query .= $where_clauses;
        }

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        foreach ($parameters as $param => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue(":$param", $value);
        }
        $stmt->execute();

        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name", "user", "password");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        select_product($db, $_POST);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Database problem occurred! " . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

The code will **not** work for you as is, so don't copy/paste it right away.

This function assumes that the **form names match the database names**, and will act accordingly. If your column name is `module_type`, name the form field which matches it `module_type` as well.

The advantages of such code, is that you can add more columns and more filters, and you won't have to change a single line of code :)