# Dynamic SQL function

Tags: sql, dynamic, pdo

I'm looking to build a function that will dynamically generate SQL and execute it using PDO and prepared statements without the column names/where clauses being hard coded.
The example below the where clause "Calories" and "Colour" are hard coded, I would like to have the functionality to be able to add additional criteria as well as less or no where clause if the situation demands.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
```

This is an insert function which allows you to pass in values dynamically that I created.

```
public function insert($table,$columnValueArray){ 
     $columns = implode(",",array_keys($columnValueArray)); 
     $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (?) VALUES (?)"; 
     $sth = $conn->prepare($sql); 

     foreach($columnValueArray as $singleArray){ 
         $values = implode(",",$singleArray); 
         $sth->execute(array($columns),$values); 
     } 
}
```

I want a similar function to this to create an update function, the problem is the update function requires a where clause which can change for each row in the array

Comment: Can who ever marked me down please provide a reason. I would like to know if this is not the correct way to go about this problem?

Comment: I imagine you were downvoted for not asking a question.  You state requirements but don't show any attempt at solving it yourself.

Comment: @Colin747: Please don't post code into comments. Go back and edit these new details into the question. As it stands, your question is in danger of being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made a similar answer some time ago to this question:

[PDO multi-Filter sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747756/pdo-multi-filter-sql-query/11747911#11747911)

It will dynamically build a basic `WHERE` clauses based upon named param binding from a `$_POST` array so it won't work with `?` params but to be honest here I am unsure why you are relying on the order of arrays to stop SQL injection and other such attacks since the order of arrays cannot always be garanteed in PHP.