# Multiple where conditions in select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am coding a small project and part of it involves creating a MySQL query based on user input.  The user has a lot of options to select from to build the dynamic query to the database.  I have been searching like mad to find any existing answers to my question, but they all seem to be different issues than what I am having.

Options a user can specify that modify the query:

- IP address (they can enter a whole IP or partial and it will search the whole range)

  Type (type 1 / type 2)

  Status (active / inactive)

  Carrier

The select query will change depending on if they have any of the above options select. If they choose both Types then it does not need to specify a type condition, likewise if both status are select it does not need to use the status as a condition.  If a user inputs an IP, it should search for the IP address, and if they input a carrier it should search for that carrier.

I am trying to use PDO and Prepare statements to do this, but I am wondering how I can set up the prepare and execute statements with PDO, while having so many potential options (if they select only one type and one status, or both types and one carrier, etc).

Is there any existing PDO functions/methods that will make this easier? Or will I need to create a bunch of if/else statements to check each option and append a $sql statement variable?

Comment: @ako Sorry, my question submitted before I finished it (my mouse is on the fritz and it clicks on its own).

Comment: If your SQL query will be different on each option you can have/not have, then yes, you have answered your own question _Or will I need to create a bunch of if/else statements to check each option and append a $sql statement variable_

Comment: @dbf If I use if/else statements to check for the needed `WHERE` clauses, how can I then use that $sql variable in a `PDO::Prepare`?

Comment: Just ad the `$sql` to the query? As in `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE {$sql}");`, do escape everything needed to prevent SQL injection, etc, bla, blip, yada ..

Comment: @dbf When adding the `$sql` variable in that manner I will have to add in named parameters `:type` when appending the `$sql` variable with if/else checks. Then prior to `pdo::execute` i will have to bind the values to those named parameters (basically adding a couple more steps).  Do you know if there is an easier way than that?  I don't want to defeat the purpose of `PDO::prepare` by inserting user input directly into the prepare statement (even if it is properly sanitized/escaped/etc).

Comment: Also found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747756/pdo-multi-filter-sql-query/11747911#11747911) which I will see if I can use to populate the `PDO::Prepare`.

Comment: @sircobalt Help me help you... I'm confused with all the possible scenarios. I can help you make a cool pdo statement, but could you please at least post all possible SQL statements  and all combinations of scenarios in code format? -So I can understand the situation better

Comment: @sircobalt give us field names and from names along with a list of ALL scenarios

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
<form method='post' action='queryresults.php'><br/>
    IP: <input type='string' name='ip_address'/>
    Carrier: <select name='carrier'>
        <option value='-1'>Any</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select><br/>
    Status: <select name='status'>
    <option value='-1'>Any</option>
    <option value='1'>Active</option>
    <option value='2'>Inactive</option>
    </select>
    <input type='text' name='carrier'/>
    (some submit button or more ajax/js stuff)
    </form>
```

queryresults:
(ALL INPUTS ARE SANITIZED, ARE THEY?)

```
$sql="select [some fields] from [some complex join]<br/>
      where <br/>
      (ip_address like '$ip_address' or $ip_address='') and<br/>
      (carrier=$carrier or $carrier=-1) and<br/>
      (status=$status or $status=-1) and<br/>
      (carrier like $carrier or $carrier='')<br>
     ...";
    $stmt=mysql_prepare....
```